# How to evaluate parts of a quoted expression in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Say I have a function that returns a quoted list like so:

```
(defun create-structure (n l)
  '(structure (name . n)(label . l)))
```

I'd like the function to return:

```
(create-structure foo bar)
-> '(structure (name . foo)(label . bar))
```

Instead I get as excpected:

```
-> '(structure (name . n)(label . l))
```

Comment: I think you can add a `,` just before the n, as in `'(structure (name . ,n)(label . ,l)))`

Comment: @Patrick you also need to use a backquote

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve this, Using the backquote syntax or an explicit call to list.

```
(defun create-structure-1 (n l)
  `(structure (name . ,n) (label . ,l)))

(defun create-structure-2 (n l)
  (list 'structure (cons 'name n) (cons 'label l)))
```

The GNU Emacs Lisp Reference provides a good read on the subject:
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote

Comment: You don't need to use a macro for this, a you can also use backquotes and commas in functions. And a backquote implies a single quote, so you don't need to use both. In place of your macro, you could do: `(defun create-structure (n l) \`(structure (name . ,n) (label . ,l)))`

Comment: Nice! I'm new to stackoverflow, what's the preferred way: should I update my answer according to your improvement or not?

Comment: I would update your answer, as the defmacro bit might be confusing to readers.

Comment: You are confusing the backquote syntax with the macro expansion. They are orthogonal — one can use backquotes outside `defmacro` just fine.